# Google maps zoom controls not displayed fully

Tags: android, google-maps, webview

I have a webpage that is used both as a WebApp and also inside a native Android webview. The webpage displays content from google Maps API v3.  The problem is :

I am unable to see the zoom controls fully on page load in older android devices .

I understand that this is because the older android browsers don't allow multitouch events to javascript runtime. Hence, the API shows the zoom controls. Need to find a way to atleast display the zoom control fully.

Could you please suggest, maybe a CSS fix :P

PFA the screenshot where the zoom out button is not fully rendered:

[image: Screenshot]

```
  Code:
    HTML:
        <div class="mapBody">
           <div id="map">
           </div>
        </div> 
    CSS:
    #map {
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute !important;
    }
```

Comment: @keune: the code is attached. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any content above the map? It's hard to see from your image. If so, they probably take more height than 10% of your screen, so your map doesn't fit.

Comment: @keune : yes, there is content above the map. And probably that's the reason I'm not able to see the map controls. Any way , the app developement has been suspended. So Im no longer looking for a solution. I had worked around the problem by specifying the control type and top corner positioning.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**: Since the display was proper for all the devices that supported multi touch events on JS, I just added the following property to the map instance in the JS, which basically specifies the position of the control/type of control.

```
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
        }
```

**NOTE**: this is not a solution, but just a workaround that I used since I was in a hurry and since it didn't create much trouble to the existing flow.

Comment: This shows the zoom control in the desired position for non-supporting devices. The Google Docs can be referred for other options.